# get keys and values as a string

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

giving a json

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "one" }
```

I would like to produce two strings:

- one with keys like:

  `"id", "name"`
- and one with values

  `1, "one"`

Seems trivial, but so far I don't even know where to start. Should I parse it with some JSON parser to a JSONValue and then get the keys? Is it tangible giving the dynamic nature of the JSON which can be given? Or simply take a REGEX route? Any other ideas?

Comment: The JSON type provider is pretty good, if your document has a standard structure

Comment: A JSON parser is always recommend ahead of regex because it's more flexible than regex.

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure how I would get these two strings once they are parsed.

Comment: Regex is not useful for general JSON parsing. For example regex struggles with nested arrays and objects. As other mentions the `FSharp.Data` JSON type provider would work or JSON.NET. Of course, you can also implement your own JSON recursive decent parser if you are a DIY person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to parse JSON on .NET, there's really one go-to solution in town - Newtonsoft JSON.NET.

I assume you want to parse JSON documents where you don't know the schema beforehand. JSON.NET has an object model that can be used to represent a document in memory, and you can inspect that to produce the output you want.

Here's a sample that should get you going:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let json = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"one\" }"

let rep = JObject.Parse(json)

let names, values = 
    [ for p in rep.Properties() do 
        yield p.Name, p.Value.ToObject<string>() ]
    |> List.unzip
```

Obviously the sample only handles flat documents, but it should be fairly simple to make it recursive.

If you do know the schema, you can use a type provider or use JSON.NET to deserialize a JSON document [straight into a record type](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/04/30/json-net-6-0-release-3-serialize-all-the-f).

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks @scrwtp